# Moving turtle in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need some help.  I'm working on writing my initials with turtle in python, but for whatever reason I'm unable to make the turtle move.  Even when the cursor moves, the turtle still starts in the middle of the screen.  Even though I'm using penup() and pendown().

I've pared my code down to this:

```
import turtle

  window = turtle.Screen()
  window.bgcolor("red")


  def draw_art():
    charles = turtle.Turtle()
    charles.shape("turtle")
    charles.color("yellow")
    charles.speed(2)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-100,50)
    turtle.pendown() 

    charles.back(100)
    charles.right(90)
    charles.forward(100)
    charles.right(90)
    charles.backward(100)

    window.exitonclick()

 draw_art()
```

Comment: you are moving "turtle" (in the middle of your code)... but you should be moving "charles"

Comment: thank you very much.  that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The turtle module presents the programmer with both a functional and an object-oriented interface.  You've made ***the common error*** of accidentally mixing the two.  When you write:

```
charles = turtle.Turtle()
charles.forward(100)
```

You're using the object-oriented interface on a turtle created *by you*.  (Good for you!)  But this:

```
turtle.goto(-100, 50)
```

Invokes the functional interface on the default turtle which was created *for you*.  There's a simple way to avoid this error -- instead of using this statement:

```
import turtle
```

use:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
```

This locks out the functional interface and only allows the object-oriented one.  So your example code would now look like:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def draw_art():
    charles = Turtle('turtle')
    charles.color('yellow')
    charles.speed('slow')

    charles.penup()
    charles.goto(-100, 50)
    charles.pendown()

    charles.back(100)
    charles.right(90)
    charles.forward(100)
    charles.right(90)
    charles.backward(100)

window = Screen()
window.bgcolor('red')

draw_art()

window.exitonclick()
```

A call like `turtle.goto(-100, 50)` will now generate an error: `name 'turtle' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

`def draw_art():
        charles = turtle.Turtle()`

Let's talk about the *why* of moving Charles:

Up top, you created an *instance* of the Turtle *class*, and set it to the variable *charles*.

*charles* is a *turtle*, yes, but you want to move *charles* -- he is your *instance* of this "type" called a *turtle*.

Hope that helps your understanding! For more, look into OOP in Python.

Comment: Your answer fails to explain why `turtle.goto(-100, 50)` is perfectly valid from Python's point of view even if it isn't consistent with what the OP is doing.  (Hint: it's a confusing issue for new programmers caused by an attempt to make turtle easier to use for new programmers!)

Comment: Thanks for noting that oversight, @cdlane!